# Download from remote server locally through JSON data

Tags: php, json, dropbox

I have a JSON data return from dropbox api.

eg.

```
array(size=4)
'name' => string 'api_upload_test.txt'
'mime' => boolean false
'meta' => ...
'data' => string 'Testing 1234'
```

How can I download the file from obtain through this data and save it locally?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this? https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php

The code sample which concerns you is:

```
$f = fopen("working-draft.txt", "w+b");
$fileMetadata = $dbxClient->getFile("/working-draft.txt", $f);
fclose($f);
print_r($fileMetadata);
```

Replace "working-draft.txt" with your file you want to download (array.name) and you should be fine.

Comment: The code above returns me the above JSON data. I need to download the files to my desktop locally just like how the dropbox is doing when you choose to download their files.

Comment: Are you sure the file isn't on the server? As far as I understand it, the object which gets returned contains the metadata of the file which was downloaded. Look here for further examples: https://github.com/BenTheDesigner/Dropbox/tree/master/examples